# manually repointing a git branch head to a now-detached commit object

Tags: git

I would like to re-use a commit object that's in my git database, which is currently not attached to any branch.

The scenario is as follows: let us call my last commit `A`. From `A`, I started making changes to my working tree, but soon realized I had a bug in `A` that I needed to fix.  I fixed the bug, and attempted to amend my commit without adding any of the other changes made to the working tree since the time of the `A` commit.  I accomplished this by `git reset --soft HEAD^`, and then staged only what was needed to fix the bug.  Then, instead of doing `git commit -c ORIG_HEAD`, I accidentally did `git commit -a -c ORIG_HEAD` (note the `-a`), so that I ended up adding all the other changes which I had wanted to remain unstaged.  The amended commit can be called `A'` to distinguish it from the original commit.

I have the SHA1 sum for the original commit object for `A` and all the blobs should still be present since this was recent and I didn't mark anything for expiration. I am thinking about simply editing `.git/refs/heads/branch_name` to have it point to `A`, then stage things in my working tree as I want, and re-amend the commit.

Would this be the best course of action in this scenario?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* re-point your current branch name, but I find it easier and safer just to make a *new* branch name:

```
git branch oops <hash>
```

You now have branch name `oops` remembering the hash ID you were remembering by hand.  That name protects the commit (and all of its files, and all of the other commits reachable *from* that commit and all of *their* files) from the garbage collector, more or less permanently—as permanently as as that name, or any other name, keeps them reachable.

(The reflogs, for `HEAD` and for the original branch name, keep the commits alive for at least 30 days by default, so you have that long to create the new name.)

Comment: Thanks -- once I've checked out `oops`, then I would rebase the changes in `A'` onto `oops`?  Then move my branch pointer to `oops` and allow `A'` to eventually expire?

Comment: It's up to you: by creating a name for the branch (probably one superior to `oops` :-) ) you get the ability to use all of Git for everything. My actual practice with complex rebases, for instnace, is to rename the current branch to add a number or date suffix, then do the rebase on a new branch name created from the original tip commit. I end up with `feature/foo.0` `feature/foo.1` `feature/foo.2` ... plus `feature/foo` which is the latest version. If I goofed something up, I have all my fallback versions up until I run `git branch -D feature/foo.0` or whatever to toss one.